# Web service to host app content updates

Tags: web-services

I think a service like this exists, but I can't put a name to it. Is there such a software as a service that allows an administrative user with read-write access to files, but all other users have read-only access? The main use case would be some smartphone app accessing such files, but only through that app and not directly exposed to anyone entering a direct URL.

Does such a software as a service exist and what is it called?

Comment: Free? Or what is your budget? Is your app open source?

Comment: My budget is a hobby budget, I am willing to do at most $15/month. My app will closed source.

Comment: Are you asking for a hosting service ("just somewhere to put some files")? I cannot read the question differently. Please not that this site is about *software* (not *service/hosting*) recommendation; for details, see [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a hosting provider to just put backup files, I need public access from any potential user. I guess I'm thinking something like Dropbox, except without having to fiddle with the whole right click > copy link thing.